# my api sometimes need cache data sometimes and sometimes not required?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8, clear-cache

my service sometimes need cache data sometimes and sometimes not required , so i would like to write an method that could clear cache when not needed AND #could someone help me creating a restful, java 8 spring boot#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring provides annotations that can help you with that purpose. If you conditionally need caching, you could for example use the `condition` parameter of the `@Cacheable` annotation, for example:

```java
@Cacheable(cacheNames="stuff", condition="#cached")
public List<Stuff> findAll(boolean cached) {
    // ...
}
```

In this case, if you call `findAll(true)`, it will return the cached result, while if you call `findAll(false)`, it will act as if the annotation isn't there.

Creating a REST API from it isn't that difficult, since your `cached` parameter could come from a request parameter as well:

```java
@GetMapping("/api/stuff")
@Cacheable(cacheNames="stuff", condition="#cached")
public List<Stuff> findAll(@RequestParam boolean cached) {
    // ...
}
```

Additionally, if you want to clear the cache, you can use the `@CacheEvict` annotation:

```java
@CacheEvict("stuff")
public void clearCache() {
}
```

And just like before, you can turn this is an endpoint:

```java
 @DeleteMapping("/api/stuff/cache")
 @CacheEvict("stuff")
 @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
 public void clearCache() {

 }
```

Comment: so there is no need to write any code in clearcache(){...............}?

Comment: The `@CacheEvict` clears the cache for you, so basically you don't need any code indeed.